# Displaying leadbolt ads on a phonegap android app

Tags: android, cordova, ads, leadbolt

I’ve been trying without success to get leadbolt ads to show up on an android app I created using phonegap. This is what I’ve done so far:

1. I have created a notification ad on leadbolt.com, added references to LeadboltController.jar and LeadboltPhonegapPlugin.jar files contained in my projects libs folder.
2. Added the code below to my javascript file

   ```
   var Leadbolt = function() { }
   Leadbolt.prototype.load = function(data, successCallback, failureCallback) {
   return PhoneGap.exec(successCallback, failureCallback, 'LeadboltPlugin', data[0], data);
   ```

   };

   ```
   PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
   PhoneGap.addPlugin('leadbolt', new Leadbolt());
   PluginManager.addService("LeadboltPlugin", "com.LeadboltPlugin.LeadboltPlugin");
   ```

   });
3. Sometimes I insert the code below in my javascript file or index.html, either way I see no ads.

   ```
   window.plugins.leadbolt.load(["*********"], null, null);
   ```

Am sure people must have gotten this to work on their apps. I would really appreciate any assistance offered.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Have you done this:

Open /res/xml/plugins.xml, add following lines:

```
<plugin name="LeadboltPlugin" value="com.LeadboltPlugin.LeadboltPlugin" />  
<plugin name="LeadboltNotificationPlugin" value="com.LeadboltPlugin.LeadboltNotificationPlugin" />
```

Comment: I just did and still doesn't work. Error from LogCat:'window.plugins.leadbolt' [undefined] is not an object.

Answer (score 0):

Hey not sure if this helps, but I know Leadbolt released an update to their phonegap plugin and its available in the portal. They put all ads types in one plugin which is much more convenient to use. Have you tried that?

If still not working, you should write to their support with details and they will get an answer for you. I’ve done that and its been very helpful.